# How to convert a single string to object

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple objects and trying to do a condition based on the object name. I am trying to check the name of the object based on the variable, which is a string. Is there any way to convert a single value string to object

```
 const showHtml= {
                 one: {
                      code: "<DIV>",
                       pos: "1" 
                 },
                 two: {
                      code: "<Body>",
                      pos: "2"
                  }
     } 
      const showcss= {
                 one: {
                      code: "text-align",
                       pos: "1" 
                 },
                 two: {
                      code: "float",
                      pos: "2"
                  }
     }
```

I have a string variable (showHTML and showcss). I want to return the code based on the variable, so i am doing

```
 let uVariable = localstorage.getItem("ftype")
console.log(uVariable.one.code)
```

I should get

```
   <DIV>
```

but as i am passing the string, I can't get the object name, is there any way to convert the uVariable into object?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want `JSON.parse` here. Localstorage only stores strings. In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
let uVariable = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("ftype"))
console.log(uVariable.one.code)
```

String => object, use `JSON.parse`
Object => string, use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I got the impression `uVariable` was a string like  `showHTML` and the op wanted to treat it like a variable name.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Hey, maybe I'm wrong. The OP was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

please read this code, might help you
so initially we have variable showHtml which contains json data.

you should try this

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showHtml')).one.code
```

and you can try jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/f5wz7Lv1/2/

for more explanation read below:

```
  var showHtml= {
                     one: {
                          code: "<DIV>",
                           pos: "1" 
                     },
                     two: {
                          code: "<Body>",
                          pos: "2"
                      }
         } 
          var showcss= {
                     one: {
                          code: "text-align",
                           pos: "1" 
                     },
                     two: {
                          code: "float",
                          pos: "2"
                      }
         }  



         localStorage.setItem('showcss', JSON.stringify(showcss));
localStorage.setItem('showHtml', JSON.stringify(showHtml));

alert('showHtml '+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showHtml')).one.code);

alert('showCss '+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showcss')).one.code)
```

Comment: okay, so what you want? dont you want to access string stored in localstorage and then parse it as json object ?

Comment: yes but when i use that i got the following error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

Comment: added js fiddle link, have a look, its working fine

Comment: and one more thing, don't use const use var, it confuse, when you use same window to debug or check the code, it create issues !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195425/discussion-between-binita-gyawali-and-dupinder-singh).